# Xcode shows same device twice in device selection list

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

[image]

**Details :**

Xcode version :  5.0 and 5.0.1

Devices : happens on all devices

Base SDK : I have two SDKs 6.1 and 7.0 doesn't matter which SDK i set as base.

**What happens when i click on one of them and tried to run :**

Selecting one cell compiles app using SDKs 6.1 and selecting other cell compiles app using SDKs 7.0

Both cells show same device name and setting base SDK to any of 6.1 / 7.0 doesn't affect.

First thing why Xcode shows device name twice ?

Any one face similar problem ? Is there any way to show sdk version along with device name ?

Comment: Go to Organizer and look as your device definitions.

Comment: I dont get it can you explain in more detail how i can select with correct SDK.

Comment: I just figure you can look at the definitions and figure out why there are two.  And possibly delete the bogus one.

Comment: Organizer shows only one device.

Comment: @anonymous I dont see answer there and his question has focussed on crash issue he is facing. I dont have crash like issue